# Html Table rows as multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a table for employee time-sheet.

After filling this time-sheet form I get below array.

```
Array
(
[date_from] => 2018-01-04
[date_to] => 2018-01-04
[date] => 2018-01-04
[project] => 53
[task] => 1
[time] => 05:30
[date1] => 2018-01-05
[project1] => 54
[task1] => 1
[time1] => 08:00
)
```

Now I want this array as

```
Array
(
  [date] => Array
 (
    [date_from] => 2018-01-04
    [date_to] => 2018-01-04
 )

[row1] => Array
(
       [date] => 2018-01-04
       [project] => 53
       [task] => 1
       [time] => 05:30
)

[row2] => Array
(
       [date1] => 2018-01-04
       [project1] => 53
       [task1] => 1
       [time1] => 05:30
)

)
```

some one please help me to this thing sort out.

Comment: I assume that this doesn't just end at `row2`? Why not format your incoming data via the form better. PHP does already handle nicely formatted arrays: `<input name="row[0][date]">`, `<input name="row[0][time]">`.

Comment: @FrankerZ thanks for this let me try this.But how about next row which is dynamically created by add row button.

Comment: you would look in `$_POST['row']` array, each dynamic row you add to the `name="row[0][key]` number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP already formats array nicely with arrays by including `[]` in your form. You should modify your incoming form like so (This is one example via jQuery, but there are many other ways to add additional rows with an index):

```js
var i = 0;

function addRow() {
  i++;
  $('#form')
    .append($('<br />'))
    .append('Date: ')
    .append($('<input />').attr('name', 'form[' + i + '][date]'))
    .append('Time: ')
    .append($('<input />').attr('name', 'form[' + i + '][time]'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
Date: <input name="form[0][date]" />
Time: <input name="form[0][time]" />
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add new" onclick="addRow()" />
```

The reason why I index the rows, is so that `$_POST['form'][0]` will contain both a date/time, and is segmented.

```
foreach ( $_POST['form'] as $dateTimeVals ) {
    //$date = $dateTimeVals['date'];
    //$time = $dateTimeVals['time'];
    //Sweet
}
```

I could simply omit the index, and use `date[]` and `time[]` but then will have to do a for loop to get the data:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['date']); $i++) {
    //$date = $_POST['date'][$i];
    //$time = $_POST['time'][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please please please try to use @FrankerZ solution, otherwise you may have to resort to manually testing the field name against a "white list" to determine what makes up a row

```
$postData = Array(
    'date_from' => '2018-01-04',
    'date_to' => '2018-01-04',
    'date' => '2018-01-04',
    'project' => '53',
    'task' => '1',
    'time' => '05:30',
    'date1' => '2018-01-05',
    'project1' => '54',
    'task1' => '1',
    'time1' => '08:00'
);

$rows = array();
$rowKeys = array( 'date','project','task','time');
foreach( $postData as $key => $value )
{
    if( preg_match('/\A(\D*)(\d*)\z/', $key, $match ) === 1 and in_array( $match[1], $rowKeys ) === true )
    {
        $rowKey = ( isset( $match[2] ) and empty( $match[2] ) === false ) ? 'row' . ($match[2] + 1) : 'row1';
        if( isset( $rows[ $rowKey ] ) === false )
        {
          $rows[ $rowKey ] = array();
        }
        $rows[ $rowKey ][ $match[1] ] = $value;
        unset( $postData[ $key ] );
    }
}

$rows = array_merge( array( 'date'=> $postData ), $rows );
print_r( $rows );
```

Comment: `preg_match()` seems a little extreme. Why not just increment `$i`, and see if `$_POST['date' . $i]`, `$_POST['time' . $i]`... exists?

Comment: Clean, I like it... I mean my alternative solution was a little extreme too.